# Using different gdb in emacs

Tags: gdb

I built a new version of GDB and it works properly from terminal. Now I want it to be executed when I run M-x gdb from emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `M-x gdb`, Emacs will present you with a command-line in the minibuffer, like:

```
Run gdb (like this): gdb -i=mi something
```

You can edit this to supply a path to `gdb`, like:

```
~/my/install/bin/gdb -i=mi something
```

Comment: Yes I was able to run gdb but the problem is it does not integrate as the way the old gdb did. So i cannot see the breakpoint symbol being hit, navigate the source code by stepping, etc. Is there a way to do that, may be something in .emacs file

Comment: Note that you can customize `gud-gbd-command-name` to set the default command rather than changing the path every time. You do need to include the `-i=mi` argument, though.

Comment: If it doesn't work with a new gdb, I would start by making sure that gdb is working ok; maybe running it with `-i=mi` to make sure MI mode is working -- just a smoke test.  After that maybe I would make sure Emacs is using MI correctly.  Maybe there's been some bug fixes or whatever.

Comment: By using your answer I was able to run the new gdb in emacs but it did not allow me to navigate through the source file. It is just like running gdb in a terminal. For example with the default gdb in emacs, I can step through the source code visually.